# Is it possible to declare a provider in one ngModule 'X' and make it available in another ngModule 'Y' that imports 'X'?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Basically what the title says: can providers/injectables be declared in a shared module and made available to others?

```
@ngModule({ 
  providers:[MyProvider],
  exports: [
    OneComponentModule,
    AnotherComponentModule
  ]
}) 
export class SharedModule{ }


@ngModule({
  declarations: [HeroPage],
  imports: [SharedModule]
})
export class HeroPageModule{ }


export class HeroPage {
  constructor(mp: MyProvider){ }
}
```

I have the above setup where SharedModule is an import of many PageModules, and it seems there must be a way to not have to include my provider in the ngModule of every page.

Right now, MyProvider is not recognized as an injectable in my HeroPage. Does anyone know a way to do this?

EDIT: Here's a plunker with the components of my app in question.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ttPW1r7wm0PcGsPOUusq

-JsonProvider is declared in SharedModule in providers[]

-SharedModule is then imported to HeroPageModule

-JsonProvider is injected into HeroPage, but cannot be found

AppModule bootstraps IonicApp, so I cannot include JsonProvider in the bootstrap to make it globally available.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your problem? Is it ionic-specific issue?

Comment: do you use lazy routing?

Comment: @yurzui just updated it! I don't think it's ionic specific but I do think ionic is preventing me from making components global

Comment: @Maximus no I don't

Comment: Your plunker is broken. Why did you provide JsonProvider in HeroPage?

Comment: Please reproduce it here https://plnkr.co/edit/izHqWLhqryZgD3kW9vmd?p=preview

Comment: Well the plunker is broken because the actual code is broken. I can get the app to work if I add the provider to each component by hand but I was hoping someone would know a way so I don't have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare it inside the `app.module.ts` `providers` array as shown below.Since they're not `modules`, just `providers`.After that, you can inject it on your `page` when you need that.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { backButtonText: '' }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    MyProvider,//here
  ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Components/directives/providers I declare in my AppModule aren't available in any of my pages by default. Any idea why this would occur?

Comment: You need to inject those providers on that page's `constructor` too.Then it'll available for use. Like this: `constructor(private myProvider: MyProvider) {
    }`

Comment: I have this already and it doesn't recognize MyProvider as a known element. Compile time error "Cannot find name 'MyProvider'"

Comment: Did you `import` the file? Can you show the full code of it?

Comment: Can you show the `import` file details as well as the usage of `provider`?

Comment: just updated with a plunker, the provider is being injected into HeroPage but I'm not sure how providers pass between modules or how they pass from modules to components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151436/discussion-between-chris-sterbenz-and-sampath).